# Accessing request headers in flask-restless preprocessor

Tags: python, flask, flask-restless

I'm building an API with Flask-Restless that requires an API key, that will be in the `Authorization` HTTP header.

In the Flask-Restless example [here](http://flask-restless.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) for a preprocessor:

```
def check_auth(instance_id=None, **kw):
    # Here, get the current user from the session.
    current_user = ...
    # Next, check if the user is authorized to modify the specified
    # instance of the model.
    if not is_authorized_to_modify(current_user, instance_id):
        raise ProcessingException(message='Not Authorized',
                                  status_code=401)
manager.create_api(Person, preprocessors=dict(GET_SINGLE=[check_auth]))
```

How do I retrieve the `Authorization` header in the `check_auth` function?

I have tried accessing the Flask `response` object, but it is `None` during the scope of this function. The `kw` parameter is also an empty dict.

Comment: How are you accessing the request? It should most definitely be available to a preprocessor.

Comment: At this point, I'm not touching the request at all. That's part of my issue, is I do not know how to access the request object from within the preprocessor.

Comment: Just use `from flask import request` then access that, the context will be active.

Comment: Hm.. That is what I originally tried. It was `None` though. I'll take another look at it and see if I can figure it out.

Comment: In a normal flask request-response cycle, the preprocessors and postprocessors *will* have access to `flask.request`.

Comment: I am chalking this up to debugger fail.

Comment: Martijn do you want to just answer this question with an example and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a normal Flask request-response cycle, the [`request` context](https://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reqcontext/) is active when the Flask-Restful preprocessors and postprocessors are being run.

As such, using:

```
from flask import request, abort

def check_auth(instance_id=None, **kw):
    current_user = None
    auth = request.headers.get('Authorization', '').lower()
    try:
        type_, apikey = auth.split(None, 1)
        if type_ != 'your_api_scheme':
            # invalid Authorization scheme
            ProcessingException(message='Not Authorized',
                                status_code=401)
        current_user = user_for_apikey[apikey]       
    except (ValueError, KeyError):
        # split failures or API key not valid
        ProcessingException(message='Not Authorized',
                            status_code=401)
```

should Just Work.